# Script creating dialog with two inputs

Tags: macos, user-interface, input, dialog, applescript

I need to write script which will be runnable on each macos. It has to create simple dialog with two input boxes OK and CANCEL buttons. I read that applescript can't create dialog with two inputs. What is alternative?
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a single input box and ask the user the separate two entries with a / or other special character? Then split the entry into its two parts?

Answer (score 0):

It's right, *AppleScript can't create dialog with two inputs*.

Take a look at the Script Library Dialog Toolkit Plus v1.1.0 on [macosautomation.com](https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Script_Libs.html#DialogToolkit)

> Dialog Toolkit Plus is an ASObjC-based script library for showing enhanced dialogs. Add multiple text entry fields, checkboxes, popup menus, radio buttons, path controls, extra buttons, secure fields, images, and rules to dialogs. Dialog Toolkit Plus requires macOS 10.10 or later.

Comment: sorry, I've moved my comment to the question as intended.

Answer (score 0):

--You could use two sequential dialogs:

set input1 to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the first input:" default answer "" buttons {"OK", "Cancel"} with title "First Input")

set input2 to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the second input:" default answer "" buttons {"OK", "Cancel"} with title "Second Input")

display dialog ("First Input: " & input1 & (return) & "Second Input: " & input2)